# Formatting email form response

Tags: php

I have created a form to email that uses this script:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value)
{
$formcontent .= "$field: $value\n";
}
$formcontent .= 'User-Agent: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


$recipient = "andrew.***y@***********.co.uk";
$subject = "Event feedback form";
$mailheader = "From: web.form@**********.co.uk\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
$mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";


mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Failure!");
header("location:http://www.**********.co.uk");
?>
```

This formats the mail in a pretty easy to read line by line way, but the client wants it to look more like the form it came from! Even if I could separate the lines with horizontal rules and align the responses it would be something - is this even possible?

Thanks
Jim

Comment: yes. For example, this will insert a text-based horizontal rule: `$formcontent .= "------------------\n";`

Comment: There are also a number of HTML-enabled email libraries available for PHP that would allow you to send emails with things like HTML tables, `<h1>`,`<h2>` headers, etc.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663268/sending-html-email-via-php-form?rq=1) discusses a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could format it with a html table.

```
$mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$formcontent .="<table border='1'>";
foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
  $formcontent .= "<tr>";
  $formcontent .= "<td>$field:</td> <td>$value</td>";
  $formcontent .= "</tr>";
}
$formcontent .= '<tr><td>User-Agent: </td><td>'.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'</td>';
$formcontent .= "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks everyone - all great suggestions and highly useful. Much appreciated

Comment: Hi - actually the above code only returns </table> on the form!Do I need to include a closing html tag at the end? Thanks

Comment: sorry, not sure if you got my previous post! Jim

Answer (score 6):

You can create an html email by adding the right line to your headers. Then you can add tables, paragraph tags, lines, whatever. Just remember that email clients can't render everything browsers can, so go gentle on the html.

```
$mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

Also, please be aware that the way you're creating the email is vulnerable to email injection exploits. Read more here: http://www.phpsecure.info/v2/article/MailHeadersInject.en.php

Comment: A further note on HTML in email - try to stick to old-school HTML 3.2.  This is one time when it's OK to use tables for layout.  You will want to avoid CSS where possible, and where you need it, use it inline.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't or don't want to use HTML in your emails, you can at least use tabs to align the text so it looks a little nicer.

```
$formcontent .= "$field:\t$value\n";
```

This will make the output look something like this:

```
Name:    sachleen
Email:   me@sachleen.com
Address: 123 fake st
```